# Fixing too much citrus in a chutney

Tags: flavor

I am making a cranberry chutney with honeycrisp apple and navel orange and I added too much dry orange and lemon. How do I cut the bitterness? It is plenty sweet with a bit of sugar and sweet apples. I usually add frozen orange concentrate but didn't have any. I am afraid to add it would only lead to more bitterness. Is cardamom considered bitter? I added this too.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you [edit your question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/posts/85780/edit) to include your recipe? We need that information to provide a useful answer.  Without it all we can do is guess.  Also, feel free to [take the tour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Hard to say without the recipe... but a low level fix is adding everything else except aforementioned citrus to re-balance it, and just end up with a larger quantity